# IdentityServer4 entity framework SQL Server connection string

Tags: entity-framework-core, identityserver4

I am trying to follow quickstart to setup SQL Server (not LocalDb version of SQLServer that comes with Visual Studio) as my data store. Looks like that two databases will be needed - one for configuration and the other for operation. But my problem is that I couldn't figure out what db names I should use. I created two databases using names I came up with and ran the scripts I downloaded from quickstart to create all the tables. Now, when I try to make connection, I think I will need to specify db names in my connection string, don't I? What should I use to replace the original connection string provide by quickstart - "Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;database=IdentityServer4.Quickstart.EntityFramework-4.0.0;trusted_connection=yes;" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have one database for both. But in general I would keep the configuration part in memory if the number of clients is small. Why spend hours keeping the config in a database for just a few clients and resources?

Better to just keep the users and persisted grants in a database.